# How to hide border of a specific chart?

Tags: css, flexdashboard

I'm new to css and am struggling with changing the border property for a specific chart title on a dashboard (I'm using a dashboard template with R's flexdashboard).

Specifically, I want to hide the title border. I've found that I can do this globally with: `chart-title{ border: none;}`.

However, I was hoping to apply this change to only one of my charts.

So far I've added a css class to my box with

```
## Box 1 { .firstbox }
```

I have tried to hide the title border for this class using:

```
.firstbox-title{
    border: none;
}
```

However, that doesn't do the trick. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign ID to the element like this `## Title {#firstbox .chart-title}` and then inside the `.css` file you should add the following.
`#firstbox .chart-title{border:none;}`